# Spring data JPA - How to return id of the nested mapping using projection and/or named query?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have these entities - Item

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="Item")
 public class Item 
 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="item_set_id")
    private ItemSet itemSet;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id")
    private Category category;

    @Column(name="category_name")
    private String categoryName;
    
    // 5 other fields which aren't required for the query
 }
```

and `Category` -

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Category")
public class Category
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private Category parent_id;
    
    @Column(name="name")    
    private String name;
}
```

I need to run this sql query :

```
select id, category_id, category_name from Item where item_set_id = ?
```

I am using this [1] in `ItemRepository` but the performance isn't good. It is retrieving all the fields in `Item` and `Category` (including a join with `Category` which I don't need).

[1]

```
@Query("SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE item_set_id = ?1")
List<Item> findByItemSet(Long itemSetId);
```

I'm trying to use named query and projection to improve the performance but I can't seem to get anywhere. I keep running into - `Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List findByItemSet(Long)`. I've tried creating a DTO class and an interface to do the same thing but it still doesn't work.

```
@Query("SELECT a.id, "
            + "a.category_name, a.category_id FROM Item a WHERE a.item_set_id = :itemSetId")
    List<Item> findByItemSet(Long itemSetId);
```

Any thoughts/suggestions on how to resolve this?

Edit: I'm using springboot 2.0.4-RELEASE, java 8 and MS-SQL Server 2012.

Comment: The last variant should work when you mark it as a native query, I think. If not, please post the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @JensSchauder After marking it as a native query, I'm running into - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1093 The column name item_set_id is not valid.

Comment: Here is the stack trace https://gist.github.com/collegian/7f440ef9830a70f5095cb6e943dd79cc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrongly using the column names in a HQL query whereas you should use the attributes names.

You can access attributes of the associations, that's the strength of JPA/Hibernate. Use

```
@Query("SELECT a.id, a.categoryName, a.category.id FROM Item a WHERE a.itemSet.id = :itemSetId")
List<Tuple> findByItemSet(Long itemSetId);
```

If you want entity objects, you could also use the following

```
@Query("FROM Item a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.category WHERE a.itemSet.id = :itemSetId")
List<Item> findByItemSet(Long itemSetId);
```

If you want to use a custom DTO use:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.dto.ItemDTO(a.id, a.categoryName, a.category.id) FROM Item a WHERE a.itemSet.id = :itemSetId")
List<ItemDTO> findByItemSet(@Param("itemSetId") Long itemSetId);
```

Comment: For the first one, I'm still running into this - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.itemhelperservice.data.repository.ItemRepository.findByItemSet(java.lang.Long)!

Comment: As you might see, I changed the return type to `Tuple`. You can't return managed entities this way. You would need a DTO, then you could do the following `SELECT NEW com.mycompany.MyDto(a.id, a.categoryName, a.category.id) FROM ...`

Comment: I still get the same error. I used this `@Query("SELECT new com.dto.ItemDTO(a.id, a.category_name, a.category_id) FROM Item a WHERE a.item_set_id = :itemSetId")
    List<ItemDTO> findByItemSet(@Param("itemSetId") Long itemSetId);`. category_id and category_name may be `null`. Not sure if that affects it somehow.

Comment: You are wrongly using the column names in a HQL query whereas you should use the attributes names. Use `@Query("SELECT new com.dto.ItemDTO(a.id, a.categoryName, a.category.id) FROM Item a WHERE a.itemSet.id = :itemSetId")     List<ItemDTO> findByItemSet(@Param("itemSetId") Long itemSetId);`

Comment: Sort of tangential, but in order to know this should I read hibernate documentation or are there any better resources? I have been going through Spring documentation but there are gaps in my knowledge. Also, if you could modify the answer to include this, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: I updated the answer. Well, there are plenty of books out there that you can use for learning. You can also try some tutorials like the official one from Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html